# Number of palindromic subsequences of length 5

Tags: string, algorithm

Given a String `s`, return the number of palindromic subsequences of length 5.

Test case 1:

```
input : "abcdba"
Output : 2
"abcba" and "abdba"
```

Test case 2:

```
input : "aabccba"
Output : 4
"abcba" , "abcba" , "abcba" , "abcba"
```

Max length of String: 700

My TLE Approach: O(2^n)

https://www.online-java.com/5YegWkAVad

Any inputs are highly appreciated...

Comment: ok, do you have the problem link to test my solution before answering?

Comment: Hi @nice_dev, I found it [here problem 2](https://leetcode.com/discuss/interview-question/2015559/Uber-OA)

Comment: Ok, this is what I came up with. https://onecompiler.com/java/3y3qrepty It is an O(n^2) dynamic programming approach.

Comment: Hmm, for `aaaaaaa` i think answer would be 21 (7c2). Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, it should be `21`. I will amend and let you know.

Comment: FYI, for max length of 700, the answer simply overflows even long datatype.

Comment: oh, ok, maybe we can assume that input will be provided in such a way that output fits in long datatype

Comment: From the linked problem statement: "It's guaranteed that for the given test cases the answer always fits signed 32-bit integer type."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Whenever 2 characters match, we only have to find how many palindromes of length 3 are possible in between these 2 characters.

**For example:**

```
a bcbc a
^      ^
|_ _ _ |
```

In the above example, you can find 2 palindromes of length `3` which is `bcb` and `cbc`. Hence, we can make palindromic sequence of length `5` as `abcba` or `acbca`. Hence, the answer is `2`.

- Computing how many palindromes of length 3 are possible for every substring can be time consuming if we don't cache the results when we do it the first time. So, cache those results and reuse them for queries generated by other 2 character matches. ([`a.k.a dynamic programming`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming))
- This way, the solution becomes quadratic `O(n^2)` time where `n` is length of the string.

**Snippet:**

```
private static long solve(String s){
  long ans = 0;
  int len = s.length();
  long[][] dp = new long[len][len];
  
  /* compute how many palindromes of length 3 are possible for every 2 characters match */
  for(int i = len - 2;i >= 0; --i){
    for(int j = i + 2; j < len; ++j){
      dp[i][j] = dp[i][j-1] + (dp[i + 1][j] == dp[i + 1][j-1] ? 0 : dp[i + 1][j] - dp[i + 1][j - 1]);
      if(s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)){
        dp[i][j] += j - i - 1;
      }
    }
  }
  
  /* re-use the above data to calculate for palindromes of length 5*/ 
  for(int i = 0; i < len; ++i){
    for(int j = i + 4; j < len; ++j){
      if(s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)){
        ans += dp[i + 1][j - 1];
      }
    }
  }
  
  //for(int i=0;i<len;++i) System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dp[i]));
  
  return ans;
}
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onecompiler.com/java/3y3qz7yuu)

**Update:**

```
 dp[i][j] = dp[i][j-1] + (dp[i + 1][j] == dp[i + 1][j-1] ? 0 : dp[i + 1][j] - dp[i + 1][j - 1]);
```

The above line basically mean this,

- For any substring, say `bcbcb`, with matching *first and last `b`*, the total 3 length palindromes can be addition of

  - The total count possible for `bcbc`.
  - The total count possible for `cbcb`.
  - The total count possible for `bcbcb` (which is `(j - i - 1)` in the `if` condition).
- `dp[i][j]` For the current substring at hand.
- `dp[i][j-1]` - Adding the previous substring counts of length 3. In this example, `bcbc`.
- `dp[i + 1][j]`, Adding the substring ending at current index excluding the  first character. (Here, `cbcb`).
- `dp[i + 1][j] == dp[i + 1][j-1] ? 0 : dp[i + 1][j] - dp[i + 1][j - 1]` This is to basically avoid duplicate counting for internal substrings and only adding them if there is a difference in the counts.

Comment: Nice intuition, when finding palindromes of length 3, can you please explain this part `dp[i][j] = dp[i][j-1] + (dp[i + 1][j] == dp[i + 1][j-1] ? 0 : dp[i + 1][j] - dp[i + 1][j - 1]);`

Comment: @Turtle Glad to help and attempt this. I have added an update to my answer. Hopefully, my explanation is more readable this time.

Comment: Before using the `dp` table and before discussing its long update line, I'd write down the exact definition of what it *means*. That's usually the first thing I literally write down (on paper or as a code comment), before writing the actual code. Something like `dp[i][j] = number of length-3 palindromes in s[i:j]` (the `s[i:j]` is Python notation, don't know about conventions for Java.)

Comment: @nice_dev, can we optimize memory usage? What if length of given string is upto 10000? Then dp array will give memory limit error.
Note: Asking this as referred here- https://leetcode.com/contest/biweekly-contest-92/problems/count-palindromic-subsequences/.

Comment: @SagarSikchi Will try and let you know soon. Travelling for 2-4 days now. Will return and look for an optimized one that fits the LC's question.

Answer (score 0):

***Observation:***

The preceding method is too cool because it gives the impression of a number of palindrome substrings of length 5, whereas the preceding method is o(n^2) using 2 DP. Cant we reduced to o(n) by using 3 dp.  Yes we can becuase here n should should be length of string but next  2 parameters length lie in range 0 to 25.

Eg: dp[i][j][k]  j, k is between 0 and 25. i is between 0 and the length of the string.

We can't get an idea directly from observation, so go to the institution.

***Intitution:***

- Of length 3
  For palindromic substring of length 3 should be  number of palindrome substring of length 3 would count the occurence of left to the index multiply with right side of the index .

Eg: _ s[i]_  => number of palindromic substring of length 3 should be at index is occurence of each alphabet before multiply with after index. So that it becomes palindrome of length 3.

Time complexity : o(n)

- Of length 5
  Similary for the case of length if 5 => _ _ s[i] _ _ Here number of occurence of combination of 2 characters before index multiply with after index, So that it becomes palindrome of length 5.

Eg: x y s[i] y x ; x,y belongs to a to z. Here we need to store occurence of xy before index and after index.

Time complexity : o(26 * 26 * n)

- Of length 7
  Similary for the case of length if 7 => _ _ _ s[i] _ _ _ Here number of occurence of combination of 3 characters before index multiply with after index, So that it becomes palindrome of length 7.

Eg: x y z s[i] z y x ; x,y ,z belongs to a to z. Here we need to store occurence of xyz before index and after index.

Time complexity : o(26 * 26 * 26*n)

***Code***

```
int pre[10000][26][26], suf[10000][26][26], cnts[26] = {};
int countPalindromes(string s) {
    int mod = 1e9 + 7, n = s.size(), ans = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int c = s[i] - '0';
        if (i)
            for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
                for (int k = 0; k < 26; k++) {
                    pre[i][j][k] = pre[i - 1][j][k];
                    if (k == c) pre[i][j][k] += cnts[j];
                }
        cnts[c]++;
    }
    memset(cnts, 0, sizeof(cnts));
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        int c = s[i] - '0';
        if (i < n - 1)
            for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
                for (int k = 0; k < 26; k++) {
                    suf[i][j][k] = suf[i + 1][j][k];
                    if (k == c) suf[i][j][k] += cnts[j];
                }
        cnts[c]++;
    }
    for (int i = 2; i < n - 2; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 26; j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < 26; k++)
                ans = (ans + 1LL * pre[i - 1][j][k] * suf[i + 1][j][k]) % mod;
    return ans;
}
```

***Reference***

Here's [a link](https://leetcode.com/contest/biweekly-contest-92/problems/count-palindromic-subsequences/)! for related problem , there 0 to 9, Most voted blog [for problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/count-palindromic-subsequences/discuss/2850466/C%2B%2B-Java-Python3-Counting-Prefixes-and-Suffixes).